# Does cocos2d-x have templates for OS X

Tags: macos, cocos2d-x

I run the install-templates-xcode.sh to install templates, but I can only choose to create new project from iOS templates.
Does cocos2d-x have templates for OS X?
Or I did some wrong steps...

xcode version: 4.5.1(4G1004)
cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

No, cocos2d-x does not support Mac OS X as target platform. If you want to create Mac OS X apps, use cocos2d-iphone instead.

Comment: The downloadable package includes samples for both iOS and Mac OSX. It didn't support it previously, but I believe it does now.

Comment: It has TestCpp and HelloCpp for OS X, but doesn't have templates... Maybe they will release the template soon.

Comment: The templates are not that useful. I usually just copy one of the included demo projects.